# Talking to telnet with popen doesn't fail but doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c, shell, pipe, telnet, io-redirection

I'd like to open a connection with a telnet server at `user@tst3:23` and talk to it with `popen("telnet tst3 23", "w")` (I'm not interested in the output in my program, but I'll log it in some files).

I first tried to do it with the command line with telnet and it worked:

```
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# telnet tst3 23
Trying 172.18.0.2...
Connected to tst3.
Escape character is '^]'.

ea719d50c59a login: user            
Password: 
Welcome to Alpine!

The Alpine Wiki contains a large amount of how-to guides and general
information about administrating Alpine systems.
See <http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/>.

You can setup the system with the command: setup-alpine

You may change this message by editing /etc/motd.

ea719d50c59a:~$ ls -l
total 0
ea719d50c59a:~$ exit
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp#
```

Then I added some redirections to simulate a program talking to it, and it worked too:

```
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat | telnet tst3 23 1> log.out 2> log.err
user

ls -l
exit
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat log.out 
Trying 172.18.0.2...
Connected to tst3.
Escape character is '^]'.

ea719d50c59a login: user
Password: 
Welcome to Alpine!

The Alpine Wiki contains a large amount of how-to guides and general
information about administrating Alpine systems.
See <http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/>.

You can setup the system with the command: setup-alpine

You may change this message by editing /etc/motd.

ea719d50c59a:~$ ls -l
total 0
ea719d50c59a:~$ exit
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# ;17R;17R
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat log.err 
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp#
```

For some reason I got `;17R;17R` in my command line after `cat`ing `log.out`, but the rest is as expected.

But then I just implement the same redirecting structure from a C program (with some usleep()s to avoid writing too fast for telnet), and it fails to log in (although I don't receive any errors from the pipe):

```
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat > test.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <error.h>


int main(void)
{
    FILE    *telnet;

    telnet  = popen("telnet tst3 23 1> log2.out 2> log2.err", "w");
    if (!telnet)
        error(1, errno, "error1");
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("a\n");

    if (fprintf(telnet, "user\n") <= 0)
        error(1, errno, "error2");
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("b\n");

    if (fprintf(telnet, "\n") <= 0)
        error(1, errno, "error3");
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("c\n");

    if (fprintf(telnet, "exe\n") <= 0)
        error(1, errno, "error4");
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("d\n");

    pclose(telnet);

    return  0;
}
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# gcc test.c -o test             
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# ./test 
a
b
c
d
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat log2.out 
Trying 172.18.0.2...
Connected to tst3.
Escape character is '^]'.

ea719d50c59a login: root@b385fb38298f:/tmp# cat log2.err 
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@b385fb38298f:/tmp#
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: You need to use `fflush(telnet)` after each `fprintf()` or turn off output buffering.

Comment: And wait for the password prompt before sending the password. The program on the other side is likely to clear its input buffer before reading.

Comment: @spectras That's presumably what the `usleep()` calls are for. He can't read the responses directly.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's the reason for the usleep()s.

Comment: But you still need to flush the buffer, otherwise nothing gets sent until the very end.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I was waiting to try it before commenting, but looked like the answer. Now I confirm you: `fflush(telnet)` works! :)